# Does the latest Jackrabbit snapshot work properly with Lucene 3?

Tags: java, lucene, jackrabbit

I work on a Java web based app that uses both Jackrabbit and Hibernate Search. The problem I was facing was that Jackrabbit had a heavy dependency on Lucene 2 but Search requires Lucene 3 to work. I managed to do a bit of "not so nice trickery" to get this working (i.e. I had to find a way to have both Lucene 2 and 3 JARs in my WEB-INF/lib dir without any class conflicts).

Although it all works fine, I want to get rid of Lucene 2 completely but Jackrabbit has been holding this up for me. I came across the following [link](http://jackrabbit.510166.n4.nabble.com/Lucene-upgrade-to-Version-3-0-3Lucene-upgrade-to-Version-3-0-3-td3238188.html) the other day and I see that the Jackrabbit guys have managed to upgrade to be compatible with Lucene 3 in a "sandbox" branch.

My question is has anyone out there used this sandbox version? I have not had a chance to play with it yet so I was wondering if anyone can confirm that it does in fact work with Lucene 3 and if so did you face any issues when upgrading from the last stable Jackrabbit release to this sandbox / snapshot? This will help me greatly in my decision to upgrade to this now or to wait until they have another stable release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently merged the sandbox branch into trunk. See [JCR-2415](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-2415) for details.

So the latest [Jackrabbit trunk](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/jackrabbit/trunk/) is based on Lucene 3.0.3 now. All of the test cases including integration tests pass. However since we are still very early in the release cycle there might still be some issues.

Comment: Excellent news! I'm still sceptical to use a snapshot in our production environment though, any ideas around when the next stable release will be?