# maven: add same 2 artifacts but with different versions

Tags: java, maven

Is this possible?

In my project I have Hibernate search which need apache lucene version 3.x, 
but my project also has magnolia cms which needs apache jackrabbit which in turn needs apache lucene 2.x.

The only solution would be to use lucene 3.x for hibernate search and 2.x for magnolia, but how can I do that?

thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a newer JackRabbit version. [The latest versions are based on Lucene 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970880/does-the-latest-jackrabbit-snapshot-work-properly-with-lucene-3/5103020#5103020).

If for some reason you can't do that, you will have to go through elaborate [package-renaming tasks](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) using the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), but that's nasty, so I'd go with the new version instead.